# Match column name to data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like in table.

```
Item | 7/7/15 | 7/8/15 | 7/9/15
  1  |   23   |   24   |   25
  2  |   26   |   74   |   96
```

and

I have table which has,

```
Item |  Date   | Number
1    | 7/9/15  | 56 
1    | 7/7/15  | 75 
1    | 7/8/15  | 63
```

I want to find sum of Number from `7/7/15` to `7/8/15` from table 1 and sum of the number from second table.

My table should look like

`Item | StartDate | EndDate | no. | TotalNumber`

Comment: Brrr, just seeing dates as column-names is giving me goosebumps...

Comment: MySQL actually allows slashes in column names? Can you show the output of SHOW COLUMNS FROM <tablename>?

Answer (score 2):

```
item 7/7/15 7/8/15  7/9/15      
1   23      24     25
2   26      74     96

item date number
1   7/9/15  56
1   7/7/15  75
1   7/8/15  63
```

.

```
SELECT
    i1.Item,
    '7/7/15' AS "StartDate",
    '7/8/15' AS "EndDate",
    (SELECT SUM(`7/7/15`)+SUM(`7/8/15`) FROM table1 WHERE item=i1.item) AS no,
    (SELECT SUM(number) FROM table2 WHERE item=i1.item) "TotalNumber"
FROM
    table2 i2
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 i1 on i1.item=i2.item;
item startdate enddate no TotalNumber
1   7/7/15     7/8/15  47     194
1   7/7/15     7/8/15  47     194
1   7/7/15     7/8/15  47     194
2   7/7/15     7/8/15  100
```

.

It's working..